# Proving $\int_0^1\frac{\log (1-x)}{x}\mathrm dx=-\frac{\pi^2}6$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals

It is a well known fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$. I wanted to prove this using elementary techniques. By doing some easy algebra, I found it was sufficient to prove that
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log (1-x)}{x}\mathrm dx=-\frac{\pi^2}6.$$
(By defining a function $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^2}$ and doing some integration.)

I have been trying to evaluate this integral using secondary school techniques (i.e., substitution or partial integration) but I didn't achieve much.

**Some approaches:**

**1.**
It's not hard to see that
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log (1-x)}{x}\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{1-x}\mathrm dx$$
It's not much, but the logarithm looks nicer now.

**2.**
Also, since we want $\pi$ to appear, a trigonometric substitution might be helpful. I tried subsituting $x=\sin^2t$ which gives
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}4\log(\cos t)\cdot \cot t\;\mathrm dt$$
or, using the second form,
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}4\log(\sin t)\cdot \tan t\;\mathrm dt$$
Another remark: $\int\tan a=-\log|\cos a|$ might help, because $\log|\cos a|$ appeared in the integral. But I dont's see immediately how to use this. (Absolute values within the logarithm are unnecessary because $\sin t,\cos t\geq0$ in this case.)

**3.**
Setting $x=\cos 2t$ gives
$$-2\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\log2+2\log(\sin t))\tan 2t\;\mathrm dt$$
by using the identity $\frac{1-\cos2a}{2}=\sin^2a$.
And since, by symmetry,
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\tan 2t\;\mathrm dt=0$$
the integral is just $$-4\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\log(\sin t)\tan 2t\;\mathrm dt$$
which looks quite nice.

Comment: This is "$-\mathrm{Li}_2(1)$", see [Dilogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm#Special_values), I'm sure it's evaluated somewhere. Some of your moves are also to be found in the related links.

Comment: This [Wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html) contains such a derivation (starting from the formula (23)).

Comment: The integral you are trying to evaluate by secondary school techniques cannot be evaluated by secondary school techniques.